# Can't change background of ionic side menu

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to apply some CSS to the background of an ionic side menu. My CSS is very simple:

```html
.my-menu-item {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important
}
```

I have applied this style to ion-content, ion-list, ion-item, and ion-side-menu. And never do any of the menu items get a blue background.

Is there a way to do this? If so how?

Here is my html code:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="header-text"> <!-- removed bar-stable -->
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear" menu-toggle="left">
          <i class="icon header-bar-icon ion-navicon"></i>
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear"  ng-click="shareAnywhere()">
          <i class="icon header-bar-icon ion-ios-upload-outline"></i>
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu class="my-menu-item" side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 id="menu-heading">MENU</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="my-menu-item">
      <ion-list class="my-menu-item">
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/discover">
          <span class="menu-style">DISCOVER MOVIES</span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/watchlist">
          WATCH LIST
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/home">
          TUTORIAL
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/friends">
          FRIENDS
        </ion-item>
        <!--
        <ion-item  class="item-icon-right" nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/test">
        TEST
      </ion-item>
        -->
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/news">
          NEWS
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close href="#/app/settings">
          SETTINGS
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  class="my-menu-item" menu-close ng-click="logoutUser()">
          SIGN OUT
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: how are you using this class, can you paste your ionic side menu code?

Comment: I have added my code as you can see I have blasted it with the class but to   no effect.

Comment: Change your title to actually describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: That was a typo :) it is now back to the original title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use some "span"s inside ion-item elements.
But you need to apply your styles to the ion-item > a elements.

Here's some pieces of code from one of my projects:

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ui-sref=".c1" ui-sref-active="active">1. Y</ion-item>
        <ion-item ui-sref=".c2" ui-sref-active="active">2. O</ion-item>
        <ion-item ui-sref=".c3" ui-sref-active="active">3. D</ion-item>
        <ion-item ui-sref=".c4" ui-sref-active="active">4. N</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And the SASS (*here I'm overriding the background-color of the "active" ion-item's child (a element)*)

```css
    ion-list {
        ion-item {
            &.active a {
                background-color: $darkYellow !important;
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or in CSS: (*assuming that you added the class coloredList to your ion-list*)

```css
ion-list.coloredList ion-item.active  a {
    background-color: red !important; 
}
```

With the modified HTML, in order not to color ALL the ion-lists.

```html
<ion-list class="coloredList"> ... </ion-list>
```

Comment: If I do that won't it affect every ion-list/ion-item I have not just the menu list?

Comment: I am not familiar with SASS can you explain as CSS?

Comment: You can give a class to your ion-list and affect only the ion-list using CSS!

Comment: I have cut and pasted your code but it has no affect on the background of the menu list elements.

Comment: Cut and paste better my friend! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOwQqK

I added the class "coloredList" to the ion-list and remove the ".active" selector of my ion-item so you can see that it applies to all items :)

Comment: Ah it's ok. I removed the .active and got closer to what I wanted. All of the menu items except the last one get a red background, I just have to get red of the white lines separating the items and work out why the last menu item still has a white background (something to do with the ng-click I think). Thanks for your help with this I am 80% there now.

Comment: Your codepen link gives a 500 error. The cut and paste was ok :) it was just that I want to change the background of the non active menu items. I.e. when you open the menu it has a red background throughout. Again thanks for your help getting me this far.

Comment: Codepen is sending me a 500 HTTP error so i can't get back to my example right now. But use the debug tools from your webbrowser (on chrome, right click => inspect element) to get deeper into the HTML code injected by Ionic directives. This is the key to a real deep customization (at least, this is how I proceed!).